# Serializing a JSON string as JSON in Scala/Play

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have a String with some arbitrary JSON in it.  I want to construct a `JsObject` with my JSON string as a JSON object value, not a string value.  For example, assuming my **arbitrary string** is a boring `{}` I want `{"key": {}}` and not `{"key": "{}"}`.

Here's how I'm trying to do it.

```
val myString = "{}"
Json.obj(
  "key" -> Json.parse(myString)
)
```

The error I get is

```
type mismatch; found :
  scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,java.io.Serializable]]
  required: play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper
```

I'm not sure what to do about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"{}" is an empty object.

So, to get `{"key": {}}` :

```
Json.obj("key" -> Json.obj())
```

**Update**:

Perhaps you have an old version of Play. This works under Play 2.3.x:

```
scala> import play.api.libs.json._
scala> Json.obj("foo" -> Json.parse("{}"))
res2: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"foo":{}}
```

Comment: Nope, sorry.  That was just an example for my arbitrary string.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understand your question then.

Comment: Huh.  So in describing my problem I simplified out a detail I thought wasn't important but was.  For some unknown reason I was actually doing ```Json.obj("foo" -> Map("bar" -> Json.parse("{}")))``` when I should be doing ```Json.obj("foo" -> Json.obj("bar" -> Json.parse("{}")))```.  Your answer helped me reevaluate my assumptions so thank you for the help!